# How can i verify my code coverage with vscode running Xunit and C#

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-code, code-coverage

I wonder if there are extensions available for adding code coverage with C# in Visual Studio Code in Linux... I have already searched the extensions but I'm not able to find some.

Kind regards

Answer (score 16):

This is an old question, but it's a top search engine result for this issue.   Here's a [blog article](https://www.albertobarnoy.blog/2019/03/tests-code-coverage-in-visual-studio.html) by Alberto Bar-Noy that I found which may help.

Alberto recommends using the following three VSCode Extensions to achieve code coverage statistics.

1. [coverlet](https://github.com/tonerdo/coverlet)
2. [.NET Core Test Explorer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.dotnet-test-explorer)
3. [Coverage Gutters](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryanluker.vscode-coverage-gutters)

Comment: Its still the top search engine result, hope you get a lot more points than this from it.

Comment: Alberto mentions *"We are however developers and as such inherently lazy"*, yet he doesnt provide us lazy developers with the commands/snippets to run to get this set up :(